# "Picking" files for further processing

Tags: shell

Though probably a good opportunity for using just a file manager like the Midnight Commander, I wonder if there is an elegant way to do it from the shell:

Let's say I want to copy a file from one directory to another. The directory is huge and has long, complicated or even partially cryptic filenames. I don't know the exact name, only that it contains `penguin`.

1. I first do a search `find . -iname "*penguin*" | less`
2. I look at the results:

   ```
   ./l1fe_of_Penguins
   ./Fw0rld_Of_penguins
   ./FUnNy_penguin
   ```
3. I want to copy the "funny penguin" file. Then I remember some relevant parts of the intricate filename and type in the shell command, like

   ```
   cp FUn*penguin /media/share
   ```

How could I make this faster? How can I in all-text mode get the file name from the search results right as a command line argument?

Comment: 1 and 2 won't be needed with a shell like `zsh`. You can simply type `cp ./<tab><tab>` use the arrow keys to explore the directory and then continue typing out a path with `*`s if needed, Press tab again and fill in the path. One more tab and you can view/set the command's other arguments like `-r` or `-v` as well.

Comment: @Hydranix but with subdirectories it will be necessary.

Comment: @Hydranix also if you have a directory with **a lot** of files and a preliminary search is necessary

Comment: You can parse into subdirectories as well as parent directories if need be. `**/*pattern*/**` is valid and will search in both directions.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the TAB key to auto complete filesystem paths for most shells.

bash supports this and a bit more.

The most interactive shell I've come across however is zsh, with a customized configuration file like [grml's zsh config](https://grml.org/zsh/) and [oh-my-zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh).

With zsh you can do autocomplete with globs and even complete several files at once.

Without knowning what flavor of Unix or Linux you're using, the best I can tell you is to check your software repository or compile zsh yourself.

Assuming Linux due to your mention of penguins, check with your package manager for the following:

```
zsh
```

And for advanced rc files enabling support for many cool things in the shell

```
grml-zsh-config
oh-my-zsh
```

Answer (score 3):

I found a way to do it:

```
find . -iname "*penguin*" | pick | xargs -J % cp -i % /media/share
```

Comment: actually, this has problems with file names with whitespaces. In GNU xargs one can use the `-d \n` which solves the problem. I don't know how to do it with FreeBSD xargs, though.

Answer (score 0):

using `-exec` option `find` can also execute a command, ie:

```
find . -iname "*penguin*" -exec cp {} /media/share \;
```

where `{}` is substituted by a name.

btw. `man find` is great! :)

Answer (score -1):

you can try this.

remove the echo command, once you are happy with the output

```
find . -iname "*penguin*" | awk '/penguin$/' | while read filename
do
    echo "cp ${filename} /media/share"
done
```